# How to Access and Process Data Using Custom Form in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

I created a dynamic custom form using HTML/CSS and JavaScript without using the built-in Django Form but unsure how to go about accessing and processing the "POST" data once the user submitted.  I wanted to avoid the additional step of saving the data into the database because I have a back-end Python Program that I wanted to run right after the user press the "Submit" button.  Is it better to save the data, process it, and then remove it?

The form starts out on a single input field for Name/Number with an "Add" button.  If user click "Add", it will add another line with Name/Number but with a "Remove" link instead.  The "Remove" link will only remove that particular line.

To better illustrate:

```
Name: [_________]  Number: [_________]     (Add)
Name: [_________]  Number: [_________]     (Remove)
Name: [_________]  Number: [_________]     (Remove)
Name: [_________]  Number: [_________]     (Remove)

(Submit)
```

My current back-end Python Program reads in a text file and process each line one by one like so:

```
John  555-555-5555
Jane  222-222-2222
Jack  333-333-3333
```

In another word, I wanted to process the form data similar to that of a text file but couldn't see how to tie it altogether.  I hope I don't confuse anyone and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `I have a back-end Python Program that I wanted to run right after the user press the "Submit" button. Is it better to save the data, process it, and then remove it?` so why you need Django?

Comment: I'm using Django to create a web user interface where they can enter the data for me to process using my back-end python program.

Comment: maybe you should use `Flask`? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2g_jp9sfEo

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I'm adding to an already existing Django Environment so I can't really developed a whole different set of framework.  I'll keep Flask in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpResponse POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).

If you know the keys of the data, then you can access via `request.POST['KEY']`. Otherwise, iterate through the dictionary and grab what you like.

Comment: Do you have an example how that might work?  I can see obtaining the data through dictionary but how do I pass that to my python program?  Do I just call it like how I normally would after I've imported the program?

For example:

some_data = request.POST ['KEY'];
myProgram (['some_data'])

Please ignore my syntax for now, I'm just trying to understand the concept.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Import the method from your separate script and call the method, passing whatever data it requires. If the script is `script.py` and the method `foo`, then `from script import foo` and `foo(the_data)`.

Comment: Seems easy enough.  I was thrown off by the <form action="./myProgram"> which I thought that's where I'll need to call my program.  Much appreciated!